# Synchronizing with CORP and being a host using symmetricds

Tags: replication, database-replication, symmetricds

I have a question regarding SymmetricDS and trying to get a project to work.

So far I've managed to get Corp to sync with Stores and Stores with Corp

[image]

This is working as intended, changes in Store are replicated to Corp, which will broadcast the changes back to the other stores.

Corp <--> Store_PC01

Corp <--> Store_PC02

Corp <--> Store_PC03

Corp <--> Store_PC04

This is all fine, however, I'm looking to go beyond this structure, I'm looking for the computers in a store to sync with each other, I'm thinking about making a PC also a host that will only sync with the computers in the same network, as such:

[image]

and

[image]

etc etc

Is this possible with Symmetric? I'm thinking of having 3 engine files. One will communicate with corp, the second one will be the PC self-host, the third will be the client to connect to the other PCs self-hosts in the same store. Is this logic correct? Do you recommend I change anything?

The reason I'm doing this is because connection with Corp might be lost as the internet can be somewhat unstable, so this is why I need to sync the computers in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible. Yes. As long as the graph of synchronization is a tree graph, i.e. one node has only one parent to which it talks and there’s one node in the root (without a parent) that represents the referent configuration point. For each level in the graph you will need to introduce at least one new node group and define sync rules W or P between it and the node group representing its parent level

Comment: I see, so it would not be possible with it being an interconnecting mesh. Thank you Boris

Comment: It's possible to sync data between any two nodes in the graph through their common ancestor (parent of a parent...).

Comment: I see, is it possible for nodes in the same group to sync data between each other and not use a parent? For example have the STORE node group be both a W and a P, and have it sync data between every node in the group?

Comment: I pretty much want each node to be a broadcast to every node in the same group node

Comment: Each node from the same group can synchronize data by sending it to its parent which will broadcast it to all other children.